# How to merge Column cells within same DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

| Header A | Header B | Header B | Header B | Header B | Header C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ship Mode | First Class | Second Class | Third Class | Premium |  |
| Order ID |  |  |  |  |  |
| order 1 | 20.00 | 30.00 | 40.00 | 50.00 | sum |
| order 2 | 40.00 | 30.00 | 40.00 | 50.00 | sum |

---

I need to merge the header B to 4 column but the data I have is:

---

| Header A | Header B | Unnamed:1 | Unnamed:2 | Unnamed3 | Header C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ship Mode | First Class | Second Class | Third Class | Premium | - |
| Order ID |  |  |  |  |  |
| order 1 | 20.00 | 30.00 | 40.00 | 50.00 | sum |
| order 2 | 40.00 | 30.00 | 40.00 | 50.00 | sum |

---

---

I tried `np.Concatenation`, but I'm not getting the same format!

Comment: which is the starting DF and which one is the expected?

Comment: the one with unnamed is starting DF and I am expecting the top result where Header B is merged with 4 column..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# turn the column heading into a series, brings column-names in a columnar form
# replace columns starting with Unnam to np.nan
# ffill the previous row value
# reassign to the datafram

# df2 refers to your starting dataframe

df2.columns=pd.Series(df2.columns).replace(r'Unnam*',np.nan, regex=True).ffill()
df2
```

```
    Header A    Header B    Header B     Header B    Header B   Header C
0   Ship Mode   First Class Second Class Third Class Premium    -
1   Order ID    NaN         NaN          NaN             NaN    NaN
2   order 1     20.00       30.00        40.00         50.00    sum
3   order 2     40.00       30.00        40.00         50.00    sum
```